# Multilabel Classification of concatenated images

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I'm working on a side project based on multi-label classification. We consider images of 64x64 pixels made up of 4 thumbnails of 32x32 pixels that was randomly added together. The thumbnails are taken from the Cifar10 database, ending up with 40k train images, and 20k test images.

The initial goal of multi class classification becomes multilabel classification. Here is an example of the dataset.

[image: Example of the dataset]

The problem is that I tried a lot of things and the pure accuracy of the model doesn't exceed 1%, whereas the loss decreases.

Here is what I tried:

- balancing the dataset ( same proportion of images regarding the class inside the image ).
- Data augmentation up to 200k images in the train
- Transfer Learning with dozens of models with/without fine tuning, and changed the last layer.
- changing the multilabel problem to a multi class problem, I ended up with 385 classes that contains all the combinations ( I think ) of the images.
- convolution 2D with a stride of 32 and a kernel size of 32x32.
- Visio Transformer.
- Trying dozens of optimizers, with different learning rate using a learning scheduler.

I'm pretty sure that the delimitation between the thumbnails is a problem for the convolution kernel because of the decor relation of the thumbnails in their corners.

I'm out of ideas that was I'm asking this question.

Comment: Before going into the model itself you should clarify what kind of loss you are using and the accuracy used for evaluation.

Comment: What's your target vector (ground truth) if I may ask?

Comment: I used CrossEntropy Loss. And the metrics was the accuracy, binary accuracy was quiet good

Comment: The cross-entropy loss is usually used for multi-class classification, you might want to adopt binary cross-entropy for a multi-label classification problem. Could you provide the code for the training loop and evaluation so we can have a look?